# Generate Matrix from Another Matrix

Tags: octave

Started learning octave recently. How do I generate a matrix from another matrix by applying a function to each element?

eg:

- Apply 2x+1 or 2x/(x^2+1) or 1/x+3 to a 3x5 matrix A.
- The result should be a 3x5 matrix with the values now 2x+1
- if A(1,1)=1 then after the operation with output matrix B then
- B(1,1) = 2.1+1 = 3

My main concern is a function that uses the value of x like that of finding the inverse or something as indicated above.

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
B = A.*2 + 1
```

The operator `.` means application of the following operation `*` to each element of the matrix.

You will find a lot of documentation for Octave in the distribution package and on the Web. Even better, you can usually also use the extensive documentation on Matlab.

ADDED. For more complex operations you can use `arrayfun()`, e.g.

```
B = arrayfun(@(x) 2*x/(x^2+1), A)
```

Comment: Hi Jiri, that is good. I think it did not use a very good example. Suppose the function is 2x/(x^2+1) or 1/x+3. I've updated the question accordingly.thanks.

Comment: I extended my answer to handle your extended question.

Comment: Hi Jiri, that is exactly what I'm looking for. I changed my existing code that was using 2 for loops and it worked great. Now learning octave so not very familiar with the existing function. thanks.